# Load and parse a XML through an URL un Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://rama.inescporto.pt/app/api/",
                data: "method=getGraph&artist=Coldplay&ri=3&p=3&d=0.5",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: xmlParser
            });
        });

        function xmlParser(xml) {

            $('#load').fadeOut();

            $(xml).find('element').each(function(){

                $(".main").append('<div class="artist"><p class="id">' + $(this).find('id').text() + '</p><p class="name">' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</p><p class="rank">Published ' + $(this).find("rank").text() + '</p></div>');
                $(".artist").fadeIn(1000);

            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div align="center" class="loader"><img src="images/loading-spiral.gif" id="load" align="absmiddle"/></div>
    </div>
```

I think I have all correct, but the request does not happen, the success function does not kick in. Someone can see where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) browser rejects that request. You can use AJAX only on the same host (ip address and port), and the same protocol the original page is open from.

Edit:
If your page is here: `http://rama.inescporto.pt/` make sure that you are writing a correct relative path to the page you want to get through AJAX: `/app/api`.

Also, try to open `http://rama.inescporto.pt/app/api/` in a browser. Do you get XML then?

Comment: The domain is different but that I got. My domain is ni.fe.up.pt/~ncruz/alpha/, so I'm using "/alpha/api/index.php" as URL and then the data. 

http://rama.inescporto.pt/app/api does return XML, "http://ni.fe.up.pt/~ncruz/alpha/api/?method=getGraph&artist=Coldplay&ri=3&p=3&d=0.5" does, but still using the url on the same domain, I do not get to success function :/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use AJAX to send a request to a different domain.

Comment: well i'm in http://rama.inescporto.pt/app/, so I just should use "api/" then, even so it does not work :/